# factory functions for React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been reading some Eric Elliott's articles about React and how he wraps components in factory functions:

- https://medium.com/javascript-scene/jsx-looks-like-an-abomination-1c1ec351a918 <-- JSX Looks Like An Abomination. But it’s Good for You
- https://medium.com/javascript-scene/baby-s-first-reaction-2103348eccdd <-- Baby’s First Reaction. A “Hello, World” Example for React
- https://medium.com/@_ericelliott/what-do-you-mean-by-does-not-work-could-you-reproduce-the-problem-on-codepen-io-as-i-understand-d24903a14a0 <-- One of the above article comments.

If you've read one of the articles you might have seen an example code similar to this:

```
const productFactory = ( { React, PropTypes } ) => {

    const Product = ( props ) => {

        return {
            props,

            render() {
                const { name, description, price, quantity, _id } = this.props.product

                return (
                    <div className="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 product">
                        <div className="product-content">
                            <div className="product-head">
                                <div className="product-title">
                                    { name }
                                </div>
                                <div className="product-description">
                                    { description }
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div className="product-price">
                                $ { price }
                            </div>
                            <button className="btn-std btn-qty" onClick={ () => { this.props.removeProduct( _id ) } }>-</button>
                            <span className="qty">{ quantity }</span>
                            <button className="btn-std btn-qty" onClick={ () => { this.props.addProduct( _id ) } }>+</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
            }
        }
    }

    Product.propTypes = {
        product: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        addProduct: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        removeProduct: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    }

    return Product
}

export default productFactory
```

The author of these articles says about this pattern:

*I export factories for all components, rather than directly exporting the components themselves. This provides two advantages:*

*1) I always pass `React` in on an `options` object, so components don’t need to import a potentially conflicting `React` or assume that React is available as a global.* <-- https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/two-weird-tricks-that-fix-react-7cf9bbdef375#95b7

*2) You can relay anything you want through all components in the `options` hash, and all components will have access to it.* <-- even CSS shared styles by your app

The part I don't get is when he says "*You might also notice that the component doesn’t have any notion of what the event listeners are doing. I used **a trick here that makes the component really easy to test and reuse in any app — I wrapped it in a factory function**.*"

Why is this easier to test and reuse that having the module exporting the actual component instead of a factory function?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This method of using factories usually is to handle dependency injection (DI) and do inversion of control (IoC).

when you create a component all the dependencies and behaviour is set in stone. but with this approach your they are separated out. You can create a new components which would have the same template but with different behviour and dependencies.

There are few advantages in development but in testing this would be very useful. 
In developement

- I could use this same file in different apps to create similar components which is a huge win win for reuse.

For testing

- I could test the component by creating it with different version of react and see the differences.
- I could pass different stubs and spies instead of using the actual behaviour.
- I could use a newer version of a service or dependencies and create a new components just for testing without actually needing to create in the app directly for TDD.

These are some of the advantages that i can think of immediately and why the author recommends this approach, as far as i understand. But the actual author might have different intentions for using this approach also.